Export typescript enum cause MODULE_NOT_FOUND error
I have a types package for my project and I export this enum:
export enum Colors {
    RED = 'RED',
    BLUE = 'BLUE',
    GREEN = 'GREEN'
}

When I import this enum from another project I get Error: cannot find module ....
I noticed that when I export it as a const enum everything works fine, but I need a regular enum for this purpose.
I have tried different changes in the tsconfig.json file:

change moduleResolution values

change preserveConstEnums value to true


nothing helped.
Any ideas why this is happening and how can I fix it?

I have a similar issue but have not found any solution.  have you find any solution?
